# Can not echo results of SELECT COUNT

Tags: php, sql

i am trying to echo the result of the SQL SELECT COUNT but it seems doesn't work for me, can anyone of you help me?
The error show that

> mysql_fetch_array expects parameter 1 to be resources, boolean given
>   ....

This is my sql

```
 <?php
   $query = ("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `errors` WHERE `sta` = 0");
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $count = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   echo $count['total'];
   ?>
```

Comment: r u getting any error? and also brackets are not necessary for the $query.

Comment: Try by removing brackets from $query. $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `errors` WHERE `sta` = 0";

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated use `mysqli_query` instead

Comment: error shows that mysql_fetch_array expects parameter 1 to be resources, boolean given ....

Comment: @KheshavSewnundun i did it but it still not works

Comment: Post your table structure!!!

Comment: @Saty what do you mean when you say post my table structure? do you mean the code of html table for this ?

Comment: Add a snap of your table

Comment: Try my answer below :)

Comment: just a question.  Is there a connection to your `database` on above of the code you posted?

Comment: @roullie i forgot to add the connection :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to following code:

```
 $query = ($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM errors WHERE sta = 0");
 $count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
 echo $count['total'];
```

Hope will help you

Comment: Updated my code: please use connection variable on your sql statement

Comment: what is going on with that first line ?

Comment: @ShabbirAhmed `mysql_` does not require connection variable. Rather it is required in `mysqli_`

Comment: i did update but it can not work, it has the same error like my code

Comment: the connection comes AFTER in mysql_ and not before. I have no idea why this answer was accepted in its present state, it's incorrect.

Comment: Hi **Fred** I think you are right, but this solution for my program. Thanks

Comment: this is assuming the OP is using mysqli_ to connect with, of course. As per your edit. Otherwise, it should read as `$query = ( "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM errors WHERE sta = 0", $con);` and `mysql_fetch_array`. Then again, maybe the OP was using mysqli_ to connect with, and that is unknown. Oh well, what can you do ;-)j

Answer (score 0):

You would use [**mysql_result()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) like shown below to retrieve the output as an int.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `errors` WHERE `sta` = 0");
$result = mysql_result($query, 0, 0);
echo $result;
```

> **mysql_*** extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL
>   extension should be used.

Comment: @HoàngTrungHiếu please post your database connection php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this, you can change your query and directly use `mysql_num_rows` as it also gives the count. And I guess you only need the count so it is better way, and here is the code :

```
<?php
   $query = ("SELECT * FROM `errors` WHERE `sta` = 0");
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
   echo $count; // this will give the total count
?>
```

Comment: @Hoàng Trung Hiếu I would like to suggest you that instead of using `mysql_` you should use `mysqli_` as `mysql_` is depreacted

Comment: `echo $query` and see what output you get

Comment: So that means there's issue with your above code or the table, *try running that query in your phpmyadmin* and Please provide more code, so that we can check if there's any other issue

Answer (score 0):

// try this code...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `errors` WHERE `sta`='0'";    
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());    
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);    
$count= mysql_num_rows($result);    
echo $count;
```

Comment: Sorry but `echo $count['total'];` this won't work, unless you just need to print the `count` variable